# Show $\int _{ x }^{ \infty }{ { e }^{ { -t }^{ 2 } } } dt<\frac { { e }^{ { -x }^{ 2 } } }{ 2x } $ for $x>0$

Tags: integration, inequality, normal-distribution

> Show that $\int _{ x }^{ \infty  }{ { e }^{ { -t }^{ 2 } } } dt <\frac { { e }^{ { -x }^{ 2 } } }{ 2x } $ for every $x>0$.

My idea was to show that $\int _{ x }^{ \infty  }{ { e }^{ { -t }^{ 2 } } }$ 
convergences: with the fact that 
$$ 1+{ x }^{ 2 }\le { e }^{ { x }^{ 2 } }\quad \text{hence}\quad \frac { 1 }{ 1+{ x }^{ 2 } } \ge { e }^{ { -x }^{ 2 } }\quad \implies \int _{ x }^{ \infty  }{ { e }^{ { -t }^{ 2 } } } \le \frac { 1 }{ 1+{ x }^{ 2 } } <\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } } $$

But its obviously not where i want to arrive, can somebody help me how to solve this
Thanks for help

Comment: For a lower bound, have a look at this MO thread: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1283/erfc-lower-bound/1401

Comment: Why the tons of useless `{  }` in the question?

Comment: The complementary error function has a well-known continued fraction expansion, from which it is simple to derive accurate bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Your last comparison doesn't make sense (what property are you using?). Instead, try introducing $(2t)/(2t)$, and note that $t>x$, so $1/t<1/x$:
$$ \int_x^{\infty} e^{-t^2} \, dt = \int_x^{\infty} \frac{2te^{-t^2}}{2t} \, dt \leq  \int_x^{\infty} \frac{2te^{-t^2}}{2x} \, dt = \frac{1}{2x}\int_x^{\infty} 2te^{-t^2} \, dt = \frac{1}{2x}\left[ -e^{-t^2} \right]_x^{\infty} = \frac{e^{-x^2}}{2x}. $$

Comment: thanks.on my last comparison i was just making the fraction bigger by reducing the denominator . Could u tell me what ur thought was on using 2t/2t. It's obvious what it contributes but i'm intrested in seeing those tricks quickly

Comment: It is true that $\int_x^{\infty} e^{-t^2} \, dt \leq \int_x^{\infty} \frac{dt}{1+t^2} $, but it doesn't follow from this that $\int_x^{\infty} e^{-t^2} \, dt \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. (The latter is true, but it doesn't follow from $e^{-t^2} \leq 1/(1+t^2)$.)

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused and fairly new to integrals, which property do  I need to use to show the last comparison? And could u explain me when are tricks like 2t/2t efficient to use?

Comment: It is possible to integrate both sides of an inequality, but one can't just integrate one side, and one can't differentiate them. Showing $\int_x^{\infty} e^{-t^2} \, dt \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is relatively difficult, and probably would rely on a combination of asymptotics and power series.

Comment: There isn't any particular way to tell if introducing an extra fraction will help: if there's a function of $t^2$, it might help in an integration by parts. But $a<t<b$ in an integral $\int_a^b f(t) \, dt$ is often useful, if say $f(t)$ is decreasing. As with most things about integrals, it's a case of learning enough techniques to be able to apply *something* to reduce the difficulty of the integration.

Comment: thanks for your help,appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$\int_x^{+\infty}2xe^{-t^2}dt <\int_x^{+\infty}2te^{-t^2}dt=e^{-x^2} $